# Sculpting with mirror X do not match both sides

Tags: sculpting, mirror, draw-mode

I am following a tutorial for sculpting the issue seems to happen with any of the tools but I am for this example I am using Draw. I am also using Dyntopo and mirror on X. I am trying to add the nipples and I added the one on the right side of screen. As you can see, the one on right is sharp and well defined while the one on the left is not barely popping. It is not the only place I see the issue. Is there any reason/ideas of why this is happening ?

Using Windows 11, Blender 3.1.2

Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: maybe your object is not symmetrical anymore, in the panel next to the XYZ symmetry buttons, click on the Symmetrize button?

Comment: Also check that your scale is applied and that your origin is located at the center of the mesh.